# ftp console automation not working

Tags: c#, ftp, console

I'm needing to automate the ftp console and used code identical to what I've found elsewhere. However when the ftp console appears it does not begin with the display of `>ftp` and trying to write to it using `standardInput.Writeline` does nothing at all. Please help!

Thanks!

Code:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\ftp.exe"; 
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.Start();
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine("open");
```